# How to encapsulate multiple fields in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, encapsulation

In my C# projects, i usually try to avoid automatic setters/getters and prefer the old fashioned field setting-getting instead. for example:

```
private string m_name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    set
    {
        m_name = value;
    }
}
```

when building large classes, i usually write the fields first and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to encapsulate a single property. i am trying to find a way to encapsulate multiple fields. found a 3rd party extensions that does this - CodeHelper 1.5, but it doesn't handle the m_prefix correctly. is there another way to achieve this with the prefix?

Comment: Out of curiosity: *why*? Why do something with significantly more maintenance, and ability for mistakes (wrong field name, etc), for absolutely no reason? Indeed, specifically seeking out a 3rd party tool only illustrates (to me at least) how much this work you are making for yourself...

Comment: Agree with Marc... Much more code overhead to maintain, I only use "custom" getters/setters if there's something more the needs to be done to get/set the property.

Comment: WFIW it sounds like the sort of thing that would be pretty easy to do when Roslyn lands (if they haven't already built it in).

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for a 3rd party extension, i highly recommend [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). You're able to introduce backing fields for automatic properties and vice versa. Nevertheless, I do also agree that there is no real need to introduce backing fields if you're not doing anything else in your Getters / Setters. You are also able to debug properties without backing fields, just add a quick watch.

Comment: Resharper doesn't support multiple encapsulations.